How to handle multiple statement descriptors for different amounts under a single payment using Stripe?
I am developing a platform for contractor translation services where users can request translations for documents possibly involving multiple languages. I use Stripe's PaymentIntents API to initially charge the user. Depending on the document, multiple translators (connected accounts) may be involved, each potentially accepting different parts of the job.
My workflow is as follows:

A user requests a translation and I charge them using stripe.paymentIntents.create.

The total charge might need to be split among several translators who are independent contractors (some are LLCs) after they accept the job, I can't pay them when I charge user as I don't know which translator will accept the job.

Each translator's payment needs to appear on the user's credit card statement with a specific statement descriptor that reflects the translator’s business name.


Here's the challenge: I need to dynamically set the statement descriptor for each part of a single charge to reflect the correct translator's business name when they accept the job.
Example:

User is charged $100 for a translation.
Translator A (LLC) translates part of the document: $50 should appear on the statement under Translator A’s business name.
Translator B translates another part: $30 should appear under Translator B’s name.
My platform keeps a $20 fee.

How can I configure Stripe to handle multiple statement descriptors for different portions of a single payment intent? Is there a way to split the initial charge post-factum or must I approach this differently?
Any insights into managing these dynamic payment distributions and statement descriptors effectively would be highly appreciated.

Statement Descriptor is tight-coupled to the PaymentIntent, and as long as you have 1 PaymentIntent, you can only specify 1 Statement Descriptor, using on_behalf_of to the Connected Account Id.
The behaviour you described can only be achieved by multiple different PaymentIntents which get on_behalf_of each Translator Connected Account.

I've read about on_behalf_of: '{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}} when payment intent is created, the issue is that in my case I don't know which translator will accept the job, and I can't find documentation how to setup on behalf pf for stripe.transfers.create.
